# WPDB query - decrypting DB data

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I am trying to grab data from the DB using WPDB but I am stuck on how to decrypt the data e.g.

The data is stored as: a:2:{i:0;s:2:"92";i:1;s:2:"71";}

I want the 92 & 71 as that's my post IDs, how to I get that part from the DB using WPDB?

My code so far is:

```
$crosssells = $wpdb->get_results(
 "SELECT * 
  FROM $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE _crosssell_ids != '' 
 "
);
```

The table is only created when data is in putted in the post so I need to check if the table exists and then grab the post id's

Comment: `postmeta` table automatically created & exists. Regarding the data, it's serialized, you can use function `maybe_unserialize()` to convert it to array or object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just serialized, in WordPress, you can run [maybe_unserialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) and get back the variable/array.

```
$crosssells = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * 
  FROM $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE _crosssell_ids <> '' 
 "
);

$array = maybe_unserialize($crosssells);
```

However, there are built in functions to retrieve posts based on meta information.  You can use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to retrieve the posts and [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve meta information from a specific post id.  It's best to abstract away from direct database interaction to take advantage of the built in caching, security, etc of WordPress.